# Dropdownlist and MVC4 Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

here is my model class
public class Question

```
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PollId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }


    public string Options { get; set; }

    public int Priority { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public List<Vote> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

i want to display the option column on dropdownlist and split using comma i tried this one it display the dropdownlist but it dose not separate the values using comma for example if my option on questionid 1 is Yes;No it displays both together like Yes;No but i want to display like this one the first value will be Yes and the second one No

my controller

```
ViewBag.MyOption = new SelectListItem() { Text = "Options" , Value = "Options" };
```

and finally my view

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyOption","---Select---")
```

what should i do pls help me

Comment: Storing a comma-delimited string is a form of database denormalization. You should consider breaking your options out into another table with a foreign key back to this one (one-to-many).

Comment: even if you split, based on what you are giving the value, is the value same as text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller

```
var optionslist = options.Split(',').ToList(); //split comma seperated into list
ViewBag.MyOption = optionslist // Your List of an options
```

In your view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Select Option",new SelectList(ViewBag.MyOption))
```